# Visio Installation via Wine on OSX

Tags: linux, macos, wine, microsoft-visio, macports

When trying to install Visio 2013 using the `VisioMUI.msi` installer, I run into the following error when using `msiexec`

```
$ msiexec /i VisioMUI.msi
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x0 1 0x0 0 stub
fixme:process:SetProcessDEPPolicy (1): stub
fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation 0x0 1 0x0 0 stub
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000380, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"AbortMsi" returned 1603
```

I currently have `dotnet20` and `msxml6` installed using `winetricks` as well as a 32 bit Wine arch; is there other modules I should install? Currently running Wine through macports on OSX.

Comment: At this point in time, Office 2013 and its components (Visio 2013) are not even listed in WineHQ.  It might not be possible.